# Prevent 2 floated siblings with variable width from wrapping inside of container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm running into an issue with floats. I have two divs I need to always be side-by-side, on the same line. They should not wrap when the screen is resized down. One must be floated left, the other floated right. If the screen width is too small to display both divs entirely, then the user must be able to scroll the main window to see all content (scrollbars should be where the user expects them to be, not "inner" scroll bars). I only want scrollbars to be visible if both floated divs are not entirely visible -- the scrollbars should not be otherwise visible.

The problem is, even when I set the container to use `white-space: none;` or `overflow: visible`, the divs still wrap.

I need the divs to always stay inline with one another.

**important NOTE:** the contents of the two floated divs will be variable in width; I have hard-coded some sizes for demo sakes but those are NOT always the sizes they will be. the divs must be inline with one another regardless of their contents.

fiddle: http://jsbin.com/yidapiriya/edit?html,css,output

markup:

```
  <div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="content-container">
      <!-- the width/height of this div will be variable based on content... this is just hardcoded for demo purposes -->
      <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ads-container">
            <!-- the width/height of this div will be variable based on content... this is just hardcoded for demo purposes -->
      <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1rem 3.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-container {
  width: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25rem;
}

.ads-container {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}


.clearfix{ 

}
.clearfix:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per i understand your question you need two div be inline even if window is resize set `min-width:` to container

```
.container {
  min-width: 1400px;
  ...
}
```

[demo](https://jsbin.com/nicebuqula/edit?html,css,output)

**UPDATE**

[New Demo](https://jsbin.com/wiriduwotu/edit?html,css,output)

```
.container {
  .....
  min-width:380px;
}

.container > div{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative; 
  width: 50%; 
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because as per requirements, this would cause a scrollbar to appear in all situations where the screen is under 1400px wide. Scrollbars should only appear if the content cannot all fit. Since content width will be variable this approach is too heavy-handed.

Comment: @Prefix i have updated my answer plz check i think its upto your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `float: left` and `float: right` from the `.ads-container` and `.content-container` and set `overflow: auto;` for `.container`

Comment: this won't work as I need the float:right so that the `.ads-container` is aligned with another dom element above it on the page. Sorry